# Androidで同じ長さの図形を描く

Tags: android

下記のようなプログラムで正方形が表示されるのですが、どの端末で見ても同じ大きさの正方形を描きたいのですがどのようにすればよいでしょうか？

0.1mm単位までは気にしませんがおおよそ同じくらいの大きさにしたいです。
今だと端末ごとのpdxによって大きさがきまってしまいます。良い方法があればご連絡ください。

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new CanvasV(this));
    }
}


public class CanvasV extends View {
    private int rectW = 200;
    private int rectH = 200;
    private Rect rect;
    private Paint paint;

    public CanvasV(Context context) {
        super(context);
        rect = new Rect();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(0xFF008800);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
        rect.set(10, 10, rectW, rectH);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

環境はAndroidStudioを使っています。

Answer (score 1):

`dp`単位を使いましょう。
http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence

端末によって、ピクセル密度(1インチにいくつピクセルが詰まっているか)が異なります。これが、機種によって大きさが変わる原因です。

Androidでは、`Density-independent pixel (dp)`という単位が用意されています。計算式はdp = ピクセル数 x (160 / ピクセル密度)です。これは、160dpi(1インチに160ドット詰まっている)を基準とした単位で、ピクセル密度に依存せず、どの端末でみても同じ大きさになる単位です。

レイアウトXMLでは単位を付けることができますが、Javaコードの中ではピクセル単位で指定するので、次のようなコードでdp単位をピクセル単位にします。（先ほどの公式ドキュメントにあります）

```
// The gesture threshold expressed in dp
private static final float GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DP = 16.0f;

// Get the screen's density scale
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
// Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
mGestureThreshold = (int) (GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DP * scale + 0.5f);
```

Comment: 160dpiを基準にするのは例なのでしょうか？それとも160dpiで考えるのが一般的になっているのでしょうか？


ソースの意味は、
private static final float GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DP = 16.0f;
//GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DPに指定のdpを入れる

final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
//端末のディスプレイの大きさを取得する。

mGestureThreshold = (int) (GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DP * scale + 0.5f);
//計算して使用している端末だと16dpは何dpiかを割り出す。

であっているでしょうか？

Comment: 160dpiは、`dp`単位の定義で用いられる基準となるピクセル密度です(`dp`と`dpi`は別の単位なので注意してください)